# why does my SUB X delete an entire row of data

Tags: excel, vba

I do in my Private sub get data and move it from one sheet to another. But when i run the "Sub X", it goes back to the sheet i am getting my data from, and deleting a row ("M") of data. i have tried to corret it, but with no luck. Then i just get "mismatch".

Hope you can help, Thank you.

```
Sub MyProcedure()
    a = Worksheets("ark1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    MsgBox (a)

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim nøgletal As String, år As Integer
    Worksheets("Ark2").Select
    nøgletal = Range("B2")
    år = Range("C2")
    Worksheets("Ark1").Select
    Worksheets("Ark1").Range("A4").Select
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark1").Range("A1:A100").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark2").Range("A12:A100").Value
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark1").Range("B1:B100").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark2").Range("B12:B100").Value
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark1").Range("C1:C100").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark2").Range("C12:C100").Value
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark1").Range("E1:E100").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark2").Range("E12:E100").Value
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark1").Range("G1:G100").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark2").Range("M12:M100").Value
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark1").Range("F1:F100").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark2").Range("N12:N100").Value
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark1").Range("H1:H100").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark2").Range("O12:O100").Value
    If Worksheets("Ark1").Range("A4").Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
        Worksheets("Ark1").Range("A4").End(xlDown).Select
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = nøgletal
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = år
    Worksheets("Ark2").Select
    Worksheets("Ark2").Range("B2", "B16").Select
End Sub

Sub x()

    Dim lngDataColumns As Long
    Dim lngDataRows As Long

    lngDataColumns = 3
    lngDataRows = 50


    For t = 1 To lngDataRows

        Range("l2").Offset(((t - 1) * lngDataColumns) - 1, 0).Resize(lngDataColumns, 1).Value = _
                Application.Transpose(Range("f1:h1").Value)

        Range("M2").Offset(((t - 1) * lngDataColumns) - 1, 0).Resize(lngDataColumns, 1).Value = _
                Application.Transpose(Range("f1:h1").Offset(t).Value)

    Next t

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to define which sheet you are working on. `Range("M2")` for example, refers to the active sheet. Add something like `Thisworkbook.Sheets("MYSHEETNAME").Range(...)` instead

Comment: i tied ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark1").Range("M1:M100").Offset  but not quite working

Comment: What are you offsetting?

Comment: @RyanWildry i just added a picture of the other ark, and trying to show what i want the code to do. to move the data as from the left part and to how it is shown on the right part. so i have the dates in row L and Data in M

Answer (score 0):

If the *X* sub procedure is on a worksheet's private code sheet and not a public module code sheet, *Range* or *Cells* will **always** implicitly belong to that worksheet unless another parent worksheet is explicitly stated.

If you are having trouble specifying source and target worksheets then perhaps passing them into the *X* sub procedure as parameters would be an efficient method.

```
Option Explicit

Sub runXfer()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("ark1")    '<~~ source
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("ark2")    '<~~ target

    Xfer ws1, ws2

End Sub

Sub Xfer(w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet)

    Dim i As Long, lr As Long, cs As Long, hdr As Variant

    With w1
        cs = 3
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
        hdr = Application.Transpose(.Cells(1, "E").Resize(1, cs).Value2)

        For i = 2 To lr
            w2.Cells(3, "L").Offset((i - 2) * cs, 0).Resize(cs, 1) = hdr
            w2.Cells(3, "M").Offset((i - 2) * cs, 0).Resize(cs, 1) = _
                Application.Transpose(.Cells(i, "E").Resize(1, cs).Value2)
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

[image]